# Office Interop Word c#.net : Copying a table at a special location

Tags: .net, interop, ms-word

I'm currently working on tables in a Word template with Interop.

In my template I have a table which I want to copy (Copying will make it easier for me to fill in the data rather than inserting rows and column, because the template has a lot of write formatting). 
The new table should be inserted right under the original table. The best would be that they would look like one single table.

My problem is that I get a paragraph between the two tables. How can I avoid this?

Here is my code:

```
object oCollapseEnd = Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd;
Word.Range rng = table.Range;
rng.Collapse(ref oCollapseEnd);

Word.Table tableCopy = document.Tables.Add(rng, 1, 1, ref missing, ref missing);
table.Range.Copy();
tableCopy.Range.Paste();

Clipboard.Clear();
```

Any help would be very appreciated! :)

Answer (score 6):

So, was working more on this issue and found a solution. Guess it was just me that got confused about the range stuff. Just thought i should post it. :)

```
Word.Range range = table.Range;
range.Copy();

Word.Range rng = table.Range;
rng.SetRange(table.Range.End, table.Range.End);

Word.Table tableCopy = document.Tables.Add(rng, 1, 1, ref missing, ref missing);
tableCopy.Range.Paste();

// got an extra row for some reason -> need to delete it
table.Rows[table.Rows.Count].Delete();
```