# Office interop - copy a table 2 lines below existing table

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I am trying to copy an existing table and paste it 2 lines below the existing table.

Here is the code I have found (see [StackOverflow Question 1756226](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756226/office-interop-word-c-net-copying-a-table-at-a-special-location)) and modified:

```
oWord.Selection.MoveDown(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdUnits.wdLine, iRow+3);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range range = oWordDoc.Tables[iTable-1].Range;
range.Copy();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng = oWordDoc.Tables[iTable-1].Range;
rng.SetRange(oWordDoc.Tables[iTable-1].Range.End, oWordDoc.Tables[iTable-1].Range.End);

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table tableCopy = oWordDoc.Tables.Add(rng, 4, 7, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
tableCopy.Range.Paste();
```

Unfortunately the code is pasting the table as part of the current table instead of a new table, so consequently a new table is not added to the tables collection of the word document.

I thought this line would accomplish what I wanted:

```
oWord.Selection.MoveDown(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdUnits.wdLine, iRow+3);
```

but even though the **Selection** cursor is moved below the current table, it's pasting the copy as part of the existing one.
How can I get it to paste the table 2 lines below the end of teh existing table please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone searches for an answer to this, I did it like this:

```
oWord.Selection.Tables[1].Select();
oWord.Selection.Copy();
oWord.Selection.MoveDown(WdUnits.wdLine, 2);
oWord.Selection.Paste();
```